# How to finalize the factors to be considered for simple linear regression

Tags: linear-model

I have a list of 100 variables from which i want to filter down to the most important variables to be considered for applying simple linear regression?

Is there a method for this?
Or do i have to follow a set of procedures for finding the above?

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of methods for variable selection. Some popular methods include forward and backward stepwise variable selection and best subset variable selection. With 100 variables an exhaustive best subset selection may be very time consuming. So I would probably recommend the forward stepwise variable selection procedure.

It goes something like this:

You fit 100 different models with one variable each.

y ~ a1 * x1

y ~ a2 * x2

...

y ~ a100*x100

This first step produces 100 p-values. Choose the most significant, say xi, which will go into the model for sure. The repeat the process, this time fitting 99 different models, each containing xi plus an additional variable.

y ~ a1*x1 + ai*xi

y ~ a2*x2 + ai*xi

...

Then repeat this process as long as you find new variables with statistically significant p-values.

For a better explanation you can check chapter 3 from the book "The elements of statistical learning." The book is excellent and available for free online at http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/

Comment: That reference book you suggested is little tough for me. Do suggest a beginners book

Comment: Perhaps Introduction to Statistical Learning would work better. It is also available freely online: http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/  Section 6.1 contains an introduction to subset selection. Section 6.5 contains an example of subset selection for regression worked out in R.